# Magento 2: Override city on Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout-page, component

**Problem:**

> Cannot override city component (current is input-text), want to change
>   to select.

**Current Status**
[image]
[image]

Already tried to set custom component using javascript:
[image]

The script is triggered when checkout page is load, but all the config on script always revert back to the previous one (input-text). In this case, I cannot override from javascript.

Back to the problem above, I can override the city component from: `%My_Module%/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` but occur another problem, only show false for the option.

Need advise for this problem, thank you.

Comment: do you want drop-down for all countries or just for US or specific countries

Comment: for starting just for specific countries. No Need to integrate first, since I want to test using dummy data.